# Truncate a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to accomplish the following :

Truncate a string (first argument) if it is longer than the given maximum string length (second argument). Return the truncated string with a ... ending.

Note that inserting the three dots to the end will add to the string length.

However, if the given maximum string length num is less than or equal to 3, then the addition of the three dots does not add to the string length in determining the truncated string.

The code I have will only pass test if my num >2, otherwise it fails.

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
  // Clear out that junk in your trunk
  var trunString = "";
  if (str.length > num) {
  trunString = str.slice(0, (num -3)) + "...";
    return trunString;
  }
  return str;
}

truncateString("A-", 1);
```

Found a solution for this:

```
var trunString = "";
  if (str.length > num && num >= 4 ) {
  trunString = str.slice(0, (num - 3)) + "...";
    return trunString;
     }
  else if (str.length > num && num <= 3) {
    trunString = str.slice(0, (num)) + "...";
    return trunString;
  }
```

Comment: Note: Instead of 3 dots (3 characters), maybe you can use the ellipsis `…` character itself (single character).

Comment: Or consider those `3` characters while manipulating..Like https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/w7to3g5p/

Comment: It will as you are subtracting 3 from your num. If it is 2 or smaller then 2 will produce either 0 or negative and your slice won't work on negative numbers

Comment: What is expected output? Why are you doing this `(num -3)`?

Comment: the expected output as per the instructions i included in the question is that you must truncate the string and add '...' to the end. without the -3 you would not be accounting for the three dots...

Comment: Please clarify.  You want to always append the "..." to the answer even when n <= 3 ?

Comment: Yes, and she wants to avoid passing a negative second parameter to `slice()` (I suppose...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:`

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
    return str.length > num ?
        str.slice(0, num > 3 ? num - 3 : num) + "..." :
        str;
}

console.log(truncateString("Abcdefghijk", 5));
console.log(truncateString("A-", 1));
console.log(truncateString("Alpha", 5));
console.log(truncateString("Beta", 5));
console.log(truncateString("Epsilon", 3));
```

Comment: Up voted as your solutions are always elegant code. Yet, the question is a bit unclear.  It seems OP wants to always add "..." to the output and allow length > n when n < 3.

Comment: If you run this code it does not work. Alpha and Beta for not have ellipses.

Comment: should `'Alpha'` have dots like `'Al...'` and `'Beta'` become `'Be...'` or `'B...'`?

Comment: nice suggestion. Actually, there is no need to pass the second ternary operator. It will work also with one pair of conditions `str.length > num ? str.slice(0, num) + '...' : str;`

Answer (score 0):

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
  // clear out that junk in your trunk
  var trunString = '';
  if (str.length && str.length > num) {
    trunString = str.slice(0, num - 1) + '&hellip;';
    return trunString;
  }
  return str;
}

truncateString("A-", 1);
```

P.S.: read also @techfoobar comment, using `&hellip` HTML entity will help...

Comment: My answer assumes the string length is the number of rendered chars, ("&hellip;".length === 1), and not the lenght of the string in javascript. Hope it fills your requirements...

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution, hoping to help you

```
   function truncate(str, num) {
      // Clear out that junk in your trunk
      var newStr;
      if(num>3&&num<str.length){
        newStr=str.slice(0,num-3)+"...";
      }else if(num>=str.length){
        newStr=str;
      }else{
        newStr=str.slice(0,num)+"...";
      }
      return newStr;
    }

    truncate("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket".length);
```

Comment: Add some explanation of your answer rather than posting the code only.